# Create login page in LightSwitch ( VS2012 )

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to create login page using [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2011/12/08/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-a-lightswitch-application.aspx), but the tutorial not for Visual Studio 2012. Some of the steps could not been found in Visual 2012. Appreciate if anyone could advice or share some links how I can do login page in LightSwitch using Visual Studio 2012. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I just scanned it quickly but didn't notice any major differences to 2012. Could you state which particular steps you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

```
 If txtUsername.Text = "cu135328" And
            txtPassword.Text = "121292" Then

        MsgBox("You have access")
```